# Problem with running or uninstalling vuze on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, vuze

When I run Vuze in terminal Vuze runs with message and then crashes

> Another copy of Vuze appears to be running: failed to lock file
>
> \.azureus\.azlock
>
> Vuze will now close

and in terminal all kind of warnings like: (Vuze:3427): Gtk-WARNING

> **: Allocating size to GtkButton 0x7f7eb86e5dc0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height().
> How does the code know the
> size to allocate?
>
> Exit from Azureus complete
>
> Azureus TERMINATED.

I have tried uninstalling it but command

> sudo apt-get purge vuze

says

> Package 'vuze' is not installed, so not removed
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

I have delete `/home/my_username/.vuze` and `/.azerus` directories but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [How To](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/03/install-vuze-ubuntu-16-10/) and installed Vuze 5.7.5 and now it works

Answer (score 0):

It's on snap, also:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap find vuze
Name     Version        Developer  Notes  Summary
vuze-vs  5.7.6.0-snap1  vs         -      Vuze is a powerful, open source, bittorrent client.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
thufir@dur:~$
```

which seems like a good way to install something like this.  I've always had trouble with `vuze`, but the snap package seems okay.

see also:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1043404/45156