# Vuze-vs 5.7.6.0-snap1 (stable) fails to install in upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, vuze

[image: Vuze installtion error]

Vuze-vs 5.7.6.0-snap 1 (stable) is failing to install in 18.04 LTS. My installation is upgraded from 16.04 through 18.04. In earlier versions I have tried to install vuze but removed as it was not working as it should.

However in a fresh installation of 18.04 Vuze works fine.I have tried to purge vuze with the command sudo apt-get purge vuze-vs but there was no such installation.

Answer (score 0):

It's on snap, also:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap find vuze
Name     Version        Developer  Notes  Summary
vuze-vs  5.7.6.0-snap1  vs         -      Vuze is a powerful, open source, bittorrent client.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
thufir@dur:~$
```

which seems like a good way to install something like this.  You'll probably have to add some template files to get search working effectively.

see also:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1043402/45156